# How to allow keyboard typing for input of type file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the plugin krajee for file input. when the file is selected it displays the path. How can I also be able to type in the input beside selecting the the file from the browse button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<!-- default icons used in the plugin are from Bootstrap 5.x icon library (which can be enabled by loading CSS below) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<!-- alternatively you can use the font awesome icon library if using with `fas` theme (or Bootstrap 4.x) by uncommenting below. -->
<!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous" -->
 
<!-- the fileinput plugin styling CSS file -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput@5.2.5/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 
<!-- if using RTL (Right-To-Left) orientation, load the RTL CSS file after fileinput.css by uncommenting below -->
<!-- link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput@5.2.5/css/fileinput-rtl.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /-->
                                     <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input id="fileId" type="file" class="file form-control" data-show-upload="false" data-show-preview="false">
                                        <br />
                                        <img id="imgHeader" />
                                    </div>
<!-- the jQuery Library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<!-- piexif.min.js is needed for auto orienting image files OR when restoring exif data in resized images and when you
    wish to resize images before upload. This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput@5.2.5/js/plugins/piexif.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
<!-- sortable.min.js is only needed if you wish to sort / rearrange files in initial preview. 
    This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput@5.2.5/js/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
<!-- bootstrap.bundle.min.js below is needed if you wish to zoom and preview file content in a detail modal
    dialog. bootstrap 5.x or 4.x is supported. You can also use the bootstrap js 3.3.x versions. -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<!-- the main fileinput plugin script JS file -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput@5.2.5/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
 
<!-- following theme script is needed to use the Font Awesome 5.x theme (`fas`). Uncomment if needed. -->
<!-- script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput@5.2.5/themes/fas/theme.min.js"></script -->
 
<!-- optionally if you need translation for your language then include the locale file as mentioned below (replace LANG.js with your language locale) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput@5.2.5/js/locales/LANG.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not possible to directly type a file path in to a `type="file"` input. Depending on what you're trying to do it may be possible to have 2 separate inputs (eg a `file` and `text`) display in the UI as one, where the file is selected on one side and the text entered on the other, but the original point remains - you cannot directly type a file path in to a file input.

Comment: Yes I guess that is the case just wanted to make sure yes I was thinking about having two input of type text. thanks